# Shouldn't display header if div is empty

Tags: javascript

I have tabs on my website, but sometimes the tab doesn't contain any info like this:

```
        <div class="idTabs">
                    <div class="tabIt">
                        <a class="selected" href="#productDetails" name="Tab1">Description</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tabIt">
                        <a href="#specs" name="Tab2" class="">Specifications</a>
                    </div>
        </div>


  <div class="productInformation">

        <div class="information">

            <div id="productDetails" style="display: block; ">
                   <div class="productInfo">
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div id="specs" style="display: none; ">

            </div>
        </div>

   </div>
```

How can I make it shouldn't display the tabs if it doesn't contain any information?
Thanks

Comment: How does the page get built? Are you using a server-side language such as PHP or ASP.NET? Or are these static HTML pages?

Comment: Well, I can only edit in the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need RegEx for that. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    regex = /(\w)/;

    // div to check to be empty
    div = document.getElementsByClassName('productInfo')[0];

    if(regex.test(div.innerHTML) === false){
        document.getElementById('productDetails').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName('tabIt')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Same with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    regex = /(\w)/;

    div = $('div#productDetails div.productInfo').text();

    if(regex.test(div) === false){
        $('#productDetails').hide();
        $('.tabIt').first().hide();
    }
</script>
```

It will also hide the DIV if it contains only whitespaces.

Comment: How do I inset regex in the html? Thanks

Comment: It's JavaScript. So you simply put it into a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Kau-Boy I think you have to negate the condition and test for innerHTML.

Comment: I quickly tested it locally and now it should work for your HTML code.

Comment: @Kau-Boy Thanks, it works, but how can I get not to display the tabs if .productInfo is empty

Comment: Thanks!! but can I have insteat of class .productInfo it should include the id productDetails and class productInfo here: "div = document.getElementsByClassName('productInfo')[0];"

Comment: Ok, I think you want to hide the div#productDetails when div.productInfo is empty. That can be done with the changed code above...

Comment: @Kau-Boy My problem is that I use the class div.productInfo another time on the page so I want to be more specific and define the class div.productInfo in id=productDetails it should only select this id Thanks

Comment: I would recomment to use a framework like Prototype or jQuery. Than you can use a selector like `$$('div#productDetails div.productInfo')` (Prototype) or `$('div#productDetails div.productInfo')`` (jQuery) to select a child of another node.

Comment: where should I put in the script, Thanks, sorry for bothering

Comment: use it instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('productInfo')[0];`

Comment: But id doesn't get the jQuery, can you please edit in your post Thanks four your effort

Comment: OK, there was one "=" missing. Here you can see the working solution: http://jsbin.com/asibe3

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tab2 = document.getElementsByName('Tab2')[0];
    var specs = document.getElementById('specs');
    if (tab2.className == '') specs.style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm not asking if the id is empty, only if the class in the id is empty.

Comment: What did you mean with "the class in the id"? That makes no sense.

Comment: <div id="productDetails" style="display: block; ">
       <div class="productInfo">
       </div>
</div>          if the class is empty, Sorry for not being clear. Thanks.

Comment: @hersh I don't understand what you actually need? :) Can you explain step by step? (By the I have updated the script if this is what you need.)

Comment: It's not the CLASS that is empty, but the DIV which has a class attribute but no content.

Comment: My website has product description and specification and the product description is one tab and the specs is another tab, sometimes I don't get to fill in the descrepyion and specs and tabs stay, I want that if don't display the description and specs I don't want it to display the tabs. Thanks

Comment: You really should to that server side with languages like PHP. You might simply add a class and hide that class using CSS, so you don't need JavaScript.

Comment: If he can really edit the HTML, than he can simply remove the empty tab. I don't think he really means that he edits static pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should use innerHTML to detect the HTML content within your div like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById('specs').innerHTML == '')
        document.getElementById('specs').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```